# Nancy: How to render Html without a Context

Tags: c#, html, email, razor, nancy

I'm using Nancy as a web framework, (also) serving pages using Razor.

**In a background worker**, I'm sending Html formatted email messages. These emails are triggered offline, hence no Context.

How can I use Nancy to render an Html string, using an Html template and a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nancy supports Razor views/templating using `Nancy.Viewengines.Razor` which is documented [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine). However, as far as I know this is only suitable for displaying views back to the browser.

For sending emails, there are lots of options out there including:

- [ActionMailer.Net](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home)
- [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)
- [RazorEmail](https://github.com/markkemper1/RazorEmail)

I chose ActionMailer.Net as the brief documentation was enough to get me started...